# Beta adjusting change in market value

Tags: greeks

I’m looking at the change in market cap $m_{t} - m_{t-i}$ for index constituents over a fixed time period ($i$ years). How would you beta adjust this change in market cap? If I take the average $\beta_{i}$ over the $i$ years, how do I then get a beta adjusted market cap change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no intuitive answer, since beta is about covariance of returns with the market and not necessarily about market cap changes. Now if you think carefully, a company with a persistent $\beta$ below 1, will have lower returns than the market. So over a very long period this company would disappear (i.e. market cap would decline vs the market). The opposite for a company with a $\beta$ above 1. This company would systematically have returns above the market (if this would occur forever this company would grow to eventually become the market as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

So one possible adjustment is what bloomberg does which is to scale betas towards one:

$$\beta_{i,\text{adjusted bloomberg}} = (2/3) \beta_i + 1/3$$

So if a company has a beta below 1, bloomberg will adjust it towards one and vice-versa.